# What is the difference of shaders with extensions .Shader, .vsh, .fsh?

Tags: ios, glkit, scenekit

What is the difference between files named "name. Shader" & "name. vsh" & "name. fsh" in scene kit ?when i call some shaders in my project my model would be like a purple mask. What should i do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are three kinds of shaders when working with SceneKit.

As for every OpenGL app there are vertex shaders and fragment shaders. Vertex shaders often have the `.vert` or `.vsh` extension and fragment shaders often have the `.frag` or `.fsh` extension. These shaders are used with the `SCNProgram` class.

In addition SceneKit exposes the concept of shader modifiers which often have the `.shader` extension. Shader modifiers can affect either a vertex of fragment shader and are used with the `SCNShadable` protocol.

These file extensions are just indications and could be really anything you want.